# Cant find specific ID - Android Java

Tags: java, android

Hi guy I´m using the [roughike Bottombar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) and I want to create a OnTabSelectedListener with 5 different Tabs. Currently it´s working with 3 different Tabs but when I want to add a 4 or 5 tab I cant find the speciffic ID of the Tab.

My code looks like this right now:

```
 bbMainNavigation.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            Fragment fMainContent = null;

            if (tabId == R.id.tBarFriends) {
                cMainFragment = FriendsFragment.class;
            } else if (tabId == R.id.tBarMessage) {
                cMainFragment = MessagesFragment.class;
            } else if (tabId == R.id.tBarRadar) {
                cMainFragment = RadarFragment.class;
            } else if (tabId == R.id.tBarAccount){
                cMainFragment = AccountFragment.class;
            }
```

My xml with the Tabs looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<resources>

    <tabs>

        <tab
            icon="@drawable/friends"
            id="@+id/tBarFriends"
            title="Friends" />

        <tab
            icon="@drawable/message"
            id="@+id/tBarMessage"
            title="Message" />

        <tab
            icon="@drawable/radar"
            id="@+id/tBarRadar"
            title="Radar" />

        <tab
            icon="@drawable/account"
            id="+@id/tBarAccount"
            title="Account" />

        <tab
            icon="@drawable/settings"
            id="+@id/tab_settings"
            title="Settings" />
    </tabs>

</resources>
```

If I try to run the code I get the following error:

> Error:(40, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable tBarAccount

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Compare your last two `id`s in the XML to the ones above. You've got the `+` and the `@` swapped -- `id="+@id/tBarAccount"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <tab
        icon="@drawable/account"
        id="@+id/tBarAccount"         <<'+' must be after '@'
        title="Account" />

    <tab
        icon="@drawable/settings"
        id="@+id/tab_settings"        <<'+' must be after '@'
        title="Settings" />
```